# How can I improve performance when loading models into three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load .stl files into my viewer, and then use the orbit controls included with three.js to allow the user to move the camera around the file, and view it from all angles. The models load in successfully, but, even on higher end systems, orbiting around the part is very slow, and slows down even more the longer the viewer has been active.

What can I do to improve viewer performance?

I can't make a jsFiddle for this, or use Codepen because of the way I have my site set up, but it is live at ethanhammond.github.io, and the code can be viewed at github.com/ethanhammond/ethanhammond.github.io.

This is also my first time using three.js, and I may have some issues in my code due to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
orbitControls.addEventListener( 'change', renderScene );
```

With each change of the orbit controls you start a new render loop. So by time you have multiple render loops. Instead of listening to the `change` event, you need to put this line into your `renderScene` function:

```
orbitControls.update();
```

You may also have a look at the official examples: [misc_orbit_controls](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit). There it also says

```
//controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
```

Comment: This fixed the FPS issues, so thanks for the help. I didn't use very much from the demos originally and never caught that. Problem's fixed now.